# Subtract number in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I would like `5 left` do `-1` e.g. become `4 left`.

**HTML**

```
<span class="small">5 left</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Store the 5 left in "numberStock" variable
var numberStock = parseInt($(".small:first").text());

// Subtract with "numberStock -1"
var minusStock = numberStock - 1;

// Here comes the issue, how do I add the new content?
$(".small:first").attr(minusStock "left");
```

**Question**

How do I add the new numberStock number `4` and text `left`?

Comment: `$('.small:first').text(minusStock + ' left');`

Comment: That makes a LOT of assumptions, BTW, about the code you've provided - which, FYI, your HTML is invalid (two closing spans, but only one open span tag)

Comment: If it isn't too late, just rewrite your code logic to store numbers in proper JavaScript variables and use HTML for mere display. It'll save you a lot of headaches now and in the future.

Comment: Thanks all very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i am not sure if i understood your question, but if i did here is a way to do it , which is pretty close to what you were trying to achieve

```
var numberStock = parseInt($('.small').text())
var minusStock = numberStock - 1;
$('.small').text(minusStock + ' left');
```

here is a fiddle in case you want to test around with it
https://jsfiddle.net/09wcjp7b/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback function.

```js
// use text method with callback where second 
// argumnet is old text
$(".small:first").text(function(i, txt) {
  // replace text with decremented value
  return txt.replace(/\d+/, function(m) {
    return m - 1;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="small">5 left</span>
```

---

**UPDATE :** With pure JavaSript do something like this.

```js
// since you just want the first element use
// querySelector otherwise you need to use 
// querySelectorAll and then need to iterate 
// over them
var ele = document.querySelector(".small");

// update text content of span element
ele.textContent = ele.textContent.replace(/\d+/, function(m) {
  return m - 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="small">5 left</span>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with without jQuery? :-)

Comment: Consider making it a second part as the OP can have two options :-)

Comment: Fancy `textContent` ;-) I wish I could `+2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace:

```js
// Store the 5 left in "numberStock" variable
var numberStock = parseInt($(".small:first").text());

// Subtract with "numberStock -1"
var minusStock = numberStock - 1;
console.log(minusStock);
// Here comes the issue, how do I add the new content?
var original = $(".small:first").text();
var toAdd = original.replace(original[0], minusStock);
$(".small:first").text(toAdd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="small">5 left</span>
```

Comment: It results in `4` and **not** `4 left`

Comment: No, it's not, check the text in the span.

Comment: Ahh did not see that -- Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascript

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('small'), function (a) {
    a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/, function (v) {
        return v - 1;
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="small">5 left</span>
```

Comment: Consider `textContent` over `innerHtml`

Comment: see [Pranav C Balan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40848311/1447675)